# App not running on other devices using ad hoc distribution

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have created an ad hoc distribution of my app.  I have successfully installed it on another device using my mac.

I have then sent the app and the ad hoc provisioning profile to a colleague.  This colleague dragged the app and the provisioning profile into iTunes and then synced.

The app installs on his device but it closes immediately when you try and run it.

In the provisioning center on the website this colleagues device is linked to this provisioning profile.

Not sure what we are doing wrong, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your colleague send you a crash report to see whats going on. Maybe it is an isolated case with this specific device that maybe a simple restore can fix.